# NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces() causes System.Security Exception

Tags: c#, reflection, add-in, system.security

I have used microsoft add in framework. From the main host I am loading an add-in and in add-in I have written :

`NetworkInterface[] adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()`.
 The above line causes System.Security Exception. The complete exception message says: `[Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.].`

Please help and let me know how can I set security permissions for a dll loaded as add in(Reflection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about the classes in the `System.AddIn` namespace, then you probably want the article [How to: Activate Add-ins with Different Isolation and Security Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384196%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), and related links, where you can specify that some (or all) add-ins should have [`NetworkInformationPermission`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinformationpermission.aspx) by using a [`PermissionSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissionset_members%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).